# How to demonstrate unambiguous CFG and CNF?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, chomsky-hierarchy

I have to show that if G is an unambiguous CFG, the transformed grammar G' in CNF is also unambiguous. But couldn't come up with something concrete. I could only visualize the case where the grammar G is ambiguous, not necessarily G' will be.

Comment: It will help if you provide more details: your approach? Progress?

Comment: Please do not delete your question after receiving an answer.  Part of our mission is to build up an archive of high-quality questions and answers that will be useful not only to you but also to others in the future.  Deleting your question after receiving an answer can be considered impolite to answerers.

Comment: For similar reasons, we discourage posts that simply state an exercise-style task out of context, and expect the community to solve it.  We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your questions.

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this question is to prove the equivalent statement:

$$G^\prime \text{ ambiguous} \implies G \text{ ambiguous}$$

This statement is called the contrapositive of the original statement.

Now you can use the definition of ambiguity of a Grammar (which happens to be in CNF in your case) and work your way to proving the ambiguity of the original grammar. What's nice about proving the contrapositive is that you can focus on a single counterexample: a member of the language that has at least two different derivations in $G\prime$ and try to show that it has at least two different derivations in $G$ instead of trying to show that for all member of $G$ it must be true that there is a unique derivation in both $G$ and $G\prime$/